# create dynamic xml payload using rest assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

**Need to set xml node in my request body using rest assured before sending**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shopping>
   <category type="groceries">
      <item>
         <name></name>
         <price>10</price>
      </item>
      <item>
         <name>Coffee</name>
         <price>20</price>
      </item>
   </category>
   <category type="supplies">
      <item>
         <name>Paper</name>
         <price>5</price>
      </item>
      <item quantity="4">
         <name>Pens</name>
         <price>15</price>
      </item>
   </category>
   <category type="present">
      <item when="Aug 10">
         <name>Kathryn's Birthday</name>
         <price>200</price>
      </item>
   </category>
</shopping>
```

I need to set "name" before sending the request

```
  <item>
     <name></name>
     <price>10</price>
  </item>
```

Could anyone plz help me how to set this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of XmlSlurper library or jackson(fasterxml) library to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java classes to do this job for you without adding new dependencies.

Here is my approach

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

//In my case - I have namespaces
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document myXml = builder.parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_MY_XML)));

//Again - I have namespaces so I using this declaration
NodeList node = myXml.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.testsite.com/common", "site");
node.item(0).setTextContent("MY_SITE_NAME");

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

//Transform and save to a string
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(myXml), new StreamResult(writer));
String resultXml = writer.toString();
```

Then simply send *resultXml* string as an argument to your Rest-Assured **body(resultXml)** method. 
If you are using RequestSpecBuilder then put it right in **setBody(resultXml)** method